# How to mock a method inside an object in a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine

Given the following directive:

This will load a simple html template with 2 buttons to call the goTo function with diferent arguments.

```
function simpleMenu() {
    return {
        scope: {
            state: '='
        },
        controller: Controller,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
    };
}

function Controller($scope, $state) {
        var vm = this;
        var options = optionsService.options;
        function goTo(state) {
            switch (state){
                case 'video':
                    return $state.go('app.video');
                case 'chat':
                    return $state.go('app.chat');
            }
        }

    }
```

I want to make a test that ensure $state is being called when the goTo function is executed.

My test uses the ***directiveElement*** to save a compiled angular element and the ***directiveScope*** to get the scope of that element :

```
var directiveElem, compile, scope, directiveScope, $state;
$state = {
    go: jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue('asd')
};
beforeEach(function() {
    bard.inject('$timeout', '$state');
    inject(function($compile, $rootScope, $httpBackend, $state) {
        compile = $compile;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        $state =  $state;
    });
});
beforeEach(function() {
    directiveElem = getCompiledElement();
});

function getCompiledElement() {
    var element = angular.element('<simpleMenu></simpleMenu>');
    var compiledElement = compile(element)(scope);
    scope.$digest();
    directiveScope = element.isolateScope();
    //Here is where I suposedly inject the mocked $state
    directiveScope.$state = $state;
    return compiledElement;
}
it('should increment value on click of button', function () {
    var output = directiveScope.vm.goTo('video-specialties');
    expect($state.go).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

The last test is returning:

> Expected spy unknown to have been called.

It seems $scope is getting the correct mocked value in the directiveScope but when the return $state.go is executed it takes the $state item from some other place, maybe it is being injected by the simpleMenu()? How can i mock this object to spy it?

Comment: I think you are missing something in your code. `goTo` is not a function on `vm`. It is declared inside the scope of the controller constructor and never applied to anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was that, Bard.js was injecting the real object into the execution, so my mock was overwritten every test. The syntax that allows to inject a mocked object is:

```
    beforeEach(module(function ($provide) {
        $provide.value('$state', $state);
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `_$state_` instead of `$state` as the parameter of the `beforeEach` block.

change to this:

```
inject(function($compile, $rootScope, $httpBackend, _$state_) {
```

Comment: Sorry but _variable_ just load the real object into the test, my objective is to mock state object to return a spy